# односвязный список, проблема в добавлении элемента

Tags: c++

Проблема в функции `Insert`. При обращении к `t->a` выдает, что `t == nullptr`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct List
{

    int a;
    List* next;
};
void Print(List* c)
{
    List* print = c;

    while (print)
    {
        cout << print->a << "->";
        print = print->next;
    }

    cout << "NULL" << endl;
}
void Add_begin(List** begin)
{
    List* t = new List;
    t->a = NULL;
    t->next = NULL;
    cin >> t->a;
    t->next = *begin;
    *begin = t;
    return;
}
void Add_end(List* end)
{
    List* t = new List;
    t->a = NULL;
    t->next = NULL;
    cin >> t->a;
    end->next = t;
    return;
}
void Insert(List** begin)
{
    List* ins = new List;
    ins->a = NULL;
    ins->next = NULL;
    cin >> ins->a;

    if (*begin = NULL)
    {
        *begin = ins;
        return;
    }

    List* t = *begin;

    if (t->a > ins->a)
    {
        ins->next = t;
        *begin = ins;
        return;
    }

    List* t1 = t->next;

    while (t1)
    {
        if (ins->a >= t->a && ins->a <= t1->a)
        {
            t->next = ins;
            ins->next = t1;
            return;
        }

        t = t1;
        t1 = t1->next;
    }

    t->next = ins;
    ins->next = NULL;
}
int main()
{
    List* begin = new List;
    begin->a = NULL;
    begin->next = NULL;
    cin >> begin->a;
    List* end = begin;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        end->next = new List;
        end = end->next;
        cin >> end->a;
        end->next = NULL;
    }

    Print(begin);
    //Add_begin(&begin);
    //Print(begin);
    Add_end(end);
    Print(begin);
    Insert(&begin);
    Print(begin);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `t->a = NULL;` - это криво.

Comment: Безотносительно проблемы: здесь явно не хватает конструктора для `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Неудивительно... См. комментарии.

```
if (*begin = NULL)   // Присваиваете *begin значение NULL
{                    // if из-за NULL не срабатывает, переход за него...
    *begin = ins;
    return;
}

List* t = *begin;    // ...сюда, присваиваем t значение *begin, равное NULL
```

Еще вопросы есть?

Comment: cпасибо, я не заметил, так и думал что ошибка глупая но найти не мог

Comment: Ну, если код заработал - закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый.